# example of a linear map in real space for which $0$ is the only eigenvalue but the map is not nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

What would be an example of a linear map in real space for which $0$ is the only eigenvalue but the map is not nilpotent? Only hint is enough.

Comment: In finite dimensions nilpotent is equivalent to all eigenvalues being zero.

Comment: What do you mean by the converse of an equivalence?

Comment: @copper.hat: sorry. How to prove that 0 is the only eigenvalue implies map is nilpotent in "real" vector space ?

Comment: Presumably Sami's answer below addresses this?

Answer (score 7):

If

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&0\\
-1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{matrix}\right)$$
then $\chi_A=-x(x^2+1)$ (*which we calculate easily using block matrices*) so $0$ is the only eigenvalue in $\mathbb R$.
The matrix $A$ isn't nilpotent since $A^3=-A$.

Answer (score -1):

This cannot happen in finite dimension.

**Hint:** Such a map would have a Jordan normal form with zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: Why the downvote here?

Comment: @copper.hat: I didn't downvote, but arguably this answer is incorrect (and Sami's answer is correct).  Of course the real culprit here is the ambiguity in the question: do we allow complex numbers as eigenvalues for real matrices or not?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I agree; it seems a pity the downvoter didn't elaborate as you have.